flutter build web does not split main.dart.js into parts
I am trying to split my main.dart.js by using deferred imports.
When I build with flutter build web --web-renderer html --release I only get one file main.dart.js.
When deployed this fails because it cannot find main.dart.js_1.js.
Is there a flag I have to turn ON?
Note: I am using dart SDK version 3.4.0-282.1.beta (beta).

There was a bug in the beta channel. If you use now upgrade to the latest beta channel it should be fixed.

oh okay. I'm using the stable channel.

This was solved in the latest flutter version. There was indeed a bug.
